# video editing; problem animating speed

Tags: animation, video

First of all: I’ve read article here about people having similar issues with this. I’m trying to do a pretty straightforward thing. I’m using a video footage and on it a speed effect strip. I’ve animated this strip with a noise modifier to make sort of choppy. To no avail. I’ve read texts here in the forum suggesting that there might be a bug. I have tried newer versions of Blender, but no luck there either. One guy suggested making the video in to pngs. Tried that as well. Could it be that the process CPU-intensive?

PS. I’m on Windows 10 using Blender 2.7.8. But I’ve tried other newer versions as well. Same thing
[image]

Comment: I've also tried the Speed effect and found that it was buggy (or I was enable to use it), I don't know if it has been fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the "Speed factor" works, but I guess "Multiply speed" is the equivalent of the current "multiply" mode we have right now.

Your noise looks extreme, I don't really see how it varies across time, but it does go from 0 to 7, that can be a lot in a footage. My guess is the noise in speed is too intense to really see the impact correctly.

If you use a multiply-type speed, then:

- 1 = normal speed
- 2 = twice fast
- 0.5 = half speed
- -1 = reverse

There's an example linear test animation:

[image: demo gif]

Here's the same with a multiply speed with the following graph in Blender 3.6.0:

[image]

[image: demo nice graph]

Here's the same but with the default noise settings:

[image]

[image: demo default graph]

It might look as untouched, but it clearly isn't when compared to the original linear:

[image: comparison gif]